# SSRS: Display field results in a string

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a field in my SSRS report called PrimaryMemberID.  It shows the ID number for members information in the report.  The report shows this in a table, amoung other information for each member.  I was wondering if there is a way to display all PrimaryMemberID's at the bottom in the report in a string, seperated by commas?  My goal is to show them like this at the bottom of the report:

```
00000001,00000002,00000003,...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a field in my SQL to get this to work.  Couldn't find anything in SSRS.

```
STUFF((SELECT ',', a.PrimaryMemberID
        FROM #Members a
        GROUP BY a.PrimaryMemberID
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```